# Is it possible to use MockRestServiceServer to test RestTemplate on Android?

Tags: java, android, spring

I'm new to Android, and I'm trying to create a simple application that gets its data through REST API. I saw Spring for Android, which uses `RestTemplate` for issuing requests, and decided to give it a try. I'm trying to write an automated test around my code but I'm not sure if `MockRestServiceServer` can be used with the `RestTemplate` in the Spring for Android package. If this isn't possible, does Spring for Android provide an alternative way to do testing?

Comment: if you just want to make API which can be consumed by android, you may want to use JAXRS with tomcat. it is very simple. https://github.com/pankajnimgade/messenger ..
this code is written using eclipse, Maven, Jersey, JAX-RS

Comment: I'm not looking to implement the REST service itself, only the client side code in an Android app.

Comment: https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/tree/master/app/src/main/java/network/calls/activities, here you would get some example to use GET, PUT, POST, using HttpUrlConnection and OkHttp

Comment: How do you write automated tests for that?

Comment: you can use Junit for testing for both client and server sidecode,